# Is there a phrase for to describe $xf(x)$ where $f(\cdot)$ is the probability mass function?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, terminology, partial-moments

We know that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_x xf_{X}(x)$ where $f_X(\cdot)$ is the probability mass function.

Is there any phrase that we use to describe $\sum_{x\le a} xf_X(x)$, or is there any phrase that we can use to denote $xf_X(x)$?

Comment: What you call *distribution function* here seems to be pmf, the probability mass function. Can you please clarify (and edit)?

Comment: corrected the question to show pmf. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 6):

The magnitude

$$\sum_{x\le a} xf(x) \equiv E(X; X\leq a)$$

is called in some circles a "restricted" expected value (restricted in the interval $(\infty, a]$), in order to keep the familiar "expected value" terminology while making the distinction from the "truncated" expected value,

$$\sum_{x\le a} x\frac{f(x)}{F_X(a)} = E(X \mid X\leq a),$$

where $F_X(a)$ is the distribution function of $X$ evaluated at $a$.

Note the use of the symbol "$;$" in the first case, and the symbol "$\mid $" in the second that has the usual "conditional on" meaning.

The relation is

$$E(X; X\leq a) = E(X \mid X\leq a)\cdot {\rm Pr}(X\leq a).$$

And so the general expression for the decomsposition of the expected value

$$E(X) =  E(X \mid X\leq a)\cdot {\rm Pr}(X\leq a) + E(X \mid X> a)\cdot {\rm Pr}(X> a)$$

$$= E(X; X\leq a) + E(X; X> a).$$

Comment: Could you include some links or references for this uses?

Answer (score 2):

The quantity $\sum_{x\leqslant a} x^q p(x)$ if the random variable $X$ is discrete with mass function $p(x)$, or $\int_{-\infty}^a x^q f(x)\text{d}x$ if $X$ is continuous with density $f(x)$, is sometimes referred to as the 'partial' $q$th moment of $X$. If $q=1$, then you could say this is a partial (lower) first moment of $X$. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)#Partial_moments).

Comment: Thank you. I found a [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2629511) about this
though I could not find out any specific phrase for the first partial moment. Thanks for the pointer.